# Can you write an "if" statement in Mule ESB?

Tags: java, mule, esb

I have an abstract-message-processor I built that I want to encapsulate inside of a boolean evaluation so that I can turn it off under certain conditions.  I'm looking to write something like this:

```
<flow name="myFlow">
    <if expression="${myFlag} == true">
        <mynamespace:myCustomMessageProcessor .../>
    </if>
</flow>
```

Is this possible in Mule ESB?  Is there an example I can review?

Comment: From what I see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094092/how-to-kick-off-a-mule-flow-to-read-messages-from-a-jms-queue-using-an-http-endp you could use `<choice><when...>`

Comment: Do you want to perform any action after the "if" in this flow?

Comment: No, I only want to invoke the message processor under certain conditions.  I don't need any other actions.

Comment: Alex, it looks like this would work.  And here I was searching for ht e work "if/then" in the Mule documentation, instead of "choice" :) Can you post your answer as an official answer to my question?

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard content-based routing pattern present in all **ESB** products.

In **Mule**, you want to use **Choice Router** - see e.g. [Mule School: Using Flow Controls – Choice Router](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-using-flow-controls-choice-router/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use IF condition reading the value from a properties file you can do the following :-

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy" doc:description="This component is used to check the value from properties file" >
  <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
     // use your if else code here like  
     if(${myFlag} == true)
         {      
         return message.payload
         }
   </scripting:script>
 </scripting:component>
```

Let me know it worked or not ....

Answer (score 0):

Mule Choice Router is the apt option for using the if else  or if elseif implementation. Even you make use of expressions to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Mule allows the condition check by using the `<choice>` router. You can define different `<when>` and one `<othterwise>` condition for fallback decisions.

```
<choice doc:name="Choice condition">
  <when expression="#[flowVars.myVar = 'on']">
    <logger level="INFO" message="Case: myVar is on" />
  </when>
  <when expression="#[flowVars.myVar = 'off']">
    <logger level="INFO" message="Case: myVar is off" />
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Case: otherwise the default route is used" />
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```